# What risks do I have now that I accidentaly opened a suspicious URL send to me by Skype?

Tags: malware, spam, url-redirection, obfuscation, skype

The following URL was sent to me by a trusted Skype contact (from my university):

**WARNING - DO NOT CLICK IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING**

```
http://bit.ly/28PPw3V#dahubas=my_skype_id
```

I clicked on it because I thought it was the score of an exam. I got redirected to `savethechildren.org`. This seemed suspicious to me, so I added '+' at the URL at bit.ly link and found out that it was redirecting to.

```
http://www.shopintoledo.com/redirect.aspx?url=http://fatjtohuh.net-www-rost...
```

This clearly looks like SPAM to me. What risks am I having now that I accidentally opened this link? I didn't give any password but my Skype address is probably into a huge spam database right now. Should I be concerned?

Comment: The worst thing you could do with Skype was resolve someone's IP from their ID because it used a p2p connection, but I believe they have moved to a cloud-based connection (you're never directly connected to someone any more). You might get some bots with chick profile pics adding you from time to time, I wouldn't be worried too much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What risks do you have?

Possibly that your computer is now infected with malicious software like a virus or a trojan horse. The following steps should be taken if you didn't already.

---

### What to do?

There are some steps you can take:

- First of all, don't click on links that you don't trust or know
- Use [unshortenit.it](http://unshortenit.it) or [urlex.org](http://urlex.org/) to check where the shortened links will send you and analyse those URL's using [virustotal.com](https://virustotal.com)
- Make sure you have a virus-scanner<sup>*</sup>, anti-spyware<sup>**</sup> software (and a adblocker plugin<sup>***</sup> installed)
- Update, update, update (make sure all software including your operating system is up-to-date)
- Perform a full-system anti-virus and anti-malware scan
- Change your Skype password since it's unclear if this was caused by a compromised computer of your University contact or by your leaked Skype password
- Inform your University contact, he might be infected

<sub>For example: *[Avira Anti-Virus](https://www.avira.com/), **[Spybot Search and Destroy](https://www.safer-networking.org/dl/), ***[Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/), [Adblock](https://getadblock.com/), [uBlock Origin](https://www.ublock.org/)</sub>

---

### What caused it?

1. An annoying University contact that's trying to be funny
2. An infected University contact (that has no idea that) his computer or hacked Skype account is used for sending such messages to his Skype contacts

---

### Additional information

The technique that is used here is URL obfuscation, usually using different URL shorten services or hacked websites for redirecting traffic.

### Analyzing the URL forwarding

Below is a trace of how the URL is redirecting: **Warning:** Do not open those URLs:

```
1: http://bit.ly/28PPw3V#dahubas=my_skype_id
2: http://www.shopintoledo.com/redirect.aspx?url=http://fatjtohuh.net-www-rostizado.gq/?/welcome/site/?vuhonoh
3: http://fatjtohuh.net-www-rostizado.gq/?/welcome/site/?vuhonoh
4: http://cheergoldfulsilvermotion.com/?a=370960&c=brain&s=wee
5: http://318-inteligen.cheergoldfulsilvermotion.com/intl/vwme/inteligen/
```

### Malware detection

The first three URLs don't seem infected (by the results of virustotal.com). **The last two URLs seems to be infected** as shown in the image below ([detection rate](https://virustotal.com/en/url/ae080927a2c4221f11f6e891d760960788bdd5ec6108a4edd15270d9b83633bf/analysis/1466781779/) of 2/67, and a suspicious mark). The [detection rate](https://virustotal.com/en/url/d4214661f0a33c3e99d0266099b96e6e6a61fd8aeb69a1613ba35b2ac2c6b351/analysis/) for the domain `cheergoldfulsilvermotion.com` seems even higher (3/67, and a suspicious mark).

[image]

[Sucuri sitecheck](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/cheergoldfulsilvermotion.com) also shows that there is malicious code detected on the website, as shown in the picture below. The payload is called `mwjs-iframe-injected530?v22`, see [this report about it](http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/mwjs-iframe-injected530?v22). It seems to be related to, **don't open** `http://aspectsdesktoponepro.org/go.php?sid=4` which is again flagged as malicious by SOPHOS anti-virus on [virustotal.com](https://virustotal.com/en/url/4e1d74d8996986585a07dffff89be74ce9013804639494bee2c0035fdbf891d2/analysis/).

[image]

---

### Advanced malware analysis / reverse engineering

If you like to perform advanced malware analysis or reverse engineering on the used malware in this case. **Make sure you do it in an isolated environment, for example using a isolated virtual machine.** I posted the first steps on how to do so and the first results on the following two locations:

- [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/22xbAqXj)
- [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/GCLxBT3u)
- [jsunpack.jeek.org](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/?report=935169932b2770ec46ac6c6e5d29c08d170679b4)

**Update:** Further investigation shows a connection to IP address `5.45.81.159` which is also related to `fatgoldworkburnachieve.com` and `891-health.goldlovelyozmotion.com` which all seem to be infected with malware named `MW:HTA:7`, see [report here](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/5.45.81.159) and [report here](http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/malware-entry-mwhta7). Anyway, they all mostly end up redirecting to `http://fgnfdfthrv.bee.pl/?q=` wich highly blacklisted, and marked as malicious (malware) site. The deobfuscated JavaScript code that I could found on the `bee.pl` subdomain where the redirects seem to end, is this:

```
function are_cookies_enabled() {
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;
    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
        document.cookie = "testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled);
}
if (are_cookies_enabled()) {
    window.location.href = 'http://408-iq.fatgoldworkburnachieve.com/us/iwis/brain_cnn/';
} else {
    window.location.href = 'http://savethechildren.org/';
}
```

It seems that in case you had cookies enabled you get redirected to a malicious site. In case you had them disabled it seems to send you to `savethechildren.org`, which seems uninfected to me. The `http://408-iq.fatgoldworkburnachieve.com/us/iwis/brain_cnn/` seems to redirect to different URLs everytime I connect to it in different ways. Examples of where I ended are:

- `https://integrated-payments-zone.com/brain_int/?a=370945&click_id=06_84198625_849b0176-94f3-4b48-9746-b6122b7a9497&subid1=326965&netid=3&ver=old`
- `http://408-iq.fatgoldworkburnachieve.com/us/iwis/brain_cnn/`
- `http://108-iq.topggolddbestanyw.com/nl/xdxz/inteligen/`
- `http://408-iq.fatgoldworkburnachieve.com/us/iwis/brain_cnn/go.php`

Comment: Oh please tell me what the code does!  I was doing some "malware analysis" (by displacing the eval() and assigning the string to a textarea) and I accidentally executed the javascript!

Comment: @AzeezahM I did not perform a full malware analysis so I can't tell. Best thing to do is to apply the same steps like written above. Did you got redirected or did you see any symptoms of being infected or strange behaviour?

Comment: Do you know what vulnerability or vulnerabilities this exploits?

Comment: @JimmyJames I tried to find that out as well, ultimately to reference to some sort of known exploit or CVE report, but I got limited time to research it and I didn't find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

As well as malware, as already indicated in [Bob Ortiz's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128178/8340), the risks include being compromised by any of the cross-domain exploits should any vulnerabilities exist on sites you trust and are possibly logged into:

e.g.

- Cross-site scripting.
- Cross-site request forgery.
- Session fixation

i.e. Client-site attacks on the sites you use.

See the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013) for more details.