# Linkedin spam through Skype - how to check if I am infected?

Tags: malware, spam, url-redirection, skype

I am following on this question:
[What risks do I have now that I accidentaly opened a suspicious URL send to me by Skype?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128175/what-risks-do-i-have-now-that-i-accidentaly-opened-a-suspicious-url-send-to-me-b)
Since I am new, I cannot comment on this thread hence the new question ...
I also saw [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122496/how-are-spammers-using-linkedin-http-linkedin-com-slinkcode-urls) and [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141189/spammer-using-linkedin-for-redirects-dangerous-or-just-spam) but did not find an answer.

So, dumb me clicked on `https://www.linkedin.com/slink?code=dZxV84r#16501=myskypeusername` for whatever reason. Thing is, I did not get redirected to other websites but ended up on a linkedin page saying something like "Oops, this link is broken".

I ran several full system scans with Avast free and Malwarebytes free that found nothing fishy. Am I safe to assume that I was fortunate enough not to catch something ? If not, can you guys guide me through further tests ?

Many thanks, Oberom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Linkedin site is compromised or vulnerable to Open Redirections, XSS or CSRF you should be fine.

For better practice when opening suspicious links you can download sandbox browser that will isolate and protect your PC from infection.

http://www.sandboxie.com/